# How to prevent individuals or a team to edit GitHub actions based workflow of a particular repository?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a GiHub repository with GitHub actions based workflow (`/.github/workflows/build.yml`) to do CI builds.

I am from the DevOps team, my case, folks from development team are not allowed to change CI pipelines, they can change whatever they want on a feature branch except `/.github/workflows/build.yml`.

How to prevent a developer changing GitHib workflow to see his app changes passing through different type of integration build quality checks?

Is there any better approach to achieve this  other than options mentioned below?

```
1]  Through PR reviews
2]  Script/automation to validate PR to see if dev did any changes to (/.github/workflows/build.yml)
```

Comment: Question also posted on [github.com](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/issues/1628).

Answer (score 1):

With [code owners](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners) you can specify who is allowed to modify certain files like so:

```yaml
# .github/CODEOWNERS

.github/workflows/build.yml @myorg/devops-team
```

---

Somewhat off-topic, but note that [Toughtworks does not recommend to separate code and pipeline ownership](https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/techniques/separate-code-and-pipeline-ownership):

> [..] in general we find it painful and unhelpful.

Comment: **Codeowners do not restrict access** - they only affect who is assigned to PRs that change certain files.